# Cantor set--nowhere dense, complete

Tags: general-topology

I can't figure out this out.

Cantor set is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space.

Every closed subset of a complete space is also complete; thus, so is the Cantor set.

**Complete space can't be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets; thus, the Cantor set has no such representation.** (1)

Cantor set is **nowhere dense** (its interior is empty, and no intervals are contained in it)

Thus, the Cantor set is a finite (then countable) intersection of nowhere dense sets.

Contradiction with statement (1).

Where is a mistake?

Does representation in (1) refer only to infinite countable intersections?

Comment: A complete metric space $X$ cannot be written as a countable union of sets that are nowhere dense in $X$. The Cantor set is not a countable union of sets that are nowhere dense **in the Cantor set**, even though it is itself nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: A complete metric space $X$ is a Baire space, so no somewhere dense set can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets **in $X$.** In particular $X$ cannot be written as such a union.

Comment: You could have made the same mistake with a one-point subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, which is also complete.

Comment: I understand. Tnx

Comment: Another question,related to this. Can we conclude by the previous statements,that Cantor set is uncountable? If Cantor set C would be countable,it could be written as a countable union of singletons (which are nowhere dense in C) and that would be a contradiction with the statement (1)?

Comment: @darboux: You have to mention that $C$ has no isolated points, so that the singletons are actually nowhere dense, but yes, with that addition your argument for the uncountability of $C$ is correct.

Comment: I agree. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

the assumption that since its finite thus countable is false.  Countable means a bijection with N.  It can be infinite (countably infinite, or simply just stated countable)